# Regex extract header and text separately from a paragraph

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I wanted to separate out the header and it's corresponding text, separated by a delimiter `colon` from a paragraph.

**Example Paragraph**,
"INCIDENTS: Quick fox ran over. A plane drove the head. RESULT AND CONCLUSION: I got headache, and fever"

**Output I expect**: [('INCIDENTS', 'Quick fox ran over. A plane drove the head'), ('RESULT AND CONCLUSION', 'I got headache, and fever')]

I am using python and tried with `re.findall(r'([A-Z]+:)(.*?)\.', <paragraph>)`. But I haven't got the expected output.

Any help is appreciated.....

Comment: `re.findall(r'\b([A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*):\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\b([A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*):|$)', text)`, see https://regex101.com/r/0rmC38/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.findall(r'\b([A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*):\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\b(?:[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*):|$)', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0rmC38/2)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `([A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*)` - Group 1: an uppercase word and then zero or more whitespace-separated uppercase words
- `:` - a colon
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `(?=\s*\b(?:[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*):|$)` - up to the 0 or more whitespaces, a word boundary, an uppercase word and then zero or more whitespace-separated uppercase words, or end of string.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor..... Working as expected, only one change though. Have to make third capturing group as Non-Capturing group. \b([A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*):\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\b(?:[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*):|$).

Comment: One more thing if things get in this pattern,                                  **Paragraph**: "There was a beautiful garden once. INTRODUCTION: There was a beautiful village. CONCLUSION: End of the story"

**Output Expected**: [('FreeText', 'There was a beautiful garden once'), ('INTRODUCTION', 'There was a beautiful village'), ('CONCLUSION': 'End of the story')]                                                       What will be your suggestion in this case Wiktor?

Comment: @Vighnesh.PVicky You can't match `FreeText` since it is missing in the input text. This is not possible to match non-existing text.

Comment: FreeText is the key which I used for representing the text which doesn't have any header. As you can see in the above example **"There was a beautiful garden once."** dosen't have any header, so that just I added a header **FreeText** for representation.

Comment: @Vighnesh.PVicky Ok, then try `r'(\b[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*:|\A)\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\b(?:[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*):|$)'` and make sure to add `INTRODUCTION` as the first tuple first item manually. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/0rmC38/3).

Comment: Thanks @ Wiktor Stribiżew, that's perfectly working. Got one more pattern like  **"Introduction: He is here. Results: he went out CI: 34. CONCLUSION: The pen is on the table"** .                        **Output Expected**: [('Introduction', 'He is here'), ('Results', 'he went out CI: 34'), ('CONCLUSION', 'The pen is on the table')].      I am stuck with this. Any thoughts?

Comment: The assumption for the ablove is : **Heading should not be less than 3 words. So CI should be not be considered a header and heading can be in camel cases**

Comment: I am trying with this **\b([A-Z][a-z]{3,}|[A-Z]{3,}(?:\s+[A-Za-z\s\d]+)*):\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\b(?:[A-Z][a-z]{3,}|[A-Z]{3,}(\s+[A-Za-z\s\d]+)*):|$)** but dosen't work as expected